# Saída da rede neural retornando Null

Tags: javascript, inteligência-artificial, machine-learning, aprendizagem-de-máquina, redes-neurais

Eu estou fazendo uma rede neural com `brain.js`, para aprender o alfabeto. o código é o seguinte:

```js
const alfabeto = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];

function converteLetrasemNumeros(letras) {
 let alfabeto = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
 let codigos = [];
        let numeros = [];
 for (let i = 0; i < letras.length; i++) {
  codigos.push(alfabeto.indexOf(letras[i].toUpperCase()) + 1);
 }
   numeros.push(codigos);
 return numeros;
}
function converteNumerosemLetras(numero) {
  let letra;
  console.log(String.fromCharCode(numero+64));
  return letra;
}
let trainingData = [];
trainingData.push(converteLetrasemNumeros(alfabeto));

const neuralNetwork = new brain.recurrent.LSTMTimeStep({hiddenLayers: [2][3]});

console.log(neuralNetwork.train(trainingData, {errorTrash: 0.0001, iterations: 25000}));

console.log(neuralNetwork.run(converteLetrasemNumeros(["A", "B", "C"])));
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/BrainJS/brain.js/45ce6ffc/browser.js"></script>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

A saída da rede, como poderão ver na execução do código, retorna `Null`.

Comment: Utilize o campo de respostas para a solução, em vez de acrescentar na pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu já achei a solução do problema. O Erro estava neste bloco:

```
for (let i = 0; i < letras.length; i++) {
    codigos.push(alfabeto.indexOf(letras[i].toUpperCase()) + 1);
}
numeros.push(codigos);
```

Eu estava adicionado valores ao Array numeros, fora do loop, que por sua vez recebia valores de outro Array. Então o código corrigido fica assim:

```
for (let i in letras) {
    numeros.push(alfabeto.indexOf(letras[i].toUpperCase()) + 1);
}
return numeros
```